# Using external script on subPages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slight problem with using simple jQuery, css script (external) in my subpages. It works in index tho. It's supposed to slide menu pannel on left side of the page. Responsive menu basically.

Here is the js.

```
    $("#res_menu").click(function(){
    $("#left").css("left", "0px");
    $("#left").css("top", "0px");
});

$("#res_menu_close").click(function(){
    $("#left").css("left", "-999px");
    $("#left").css("top", "-999px");
});
```

Simple script right ?

It's linked in the bottom of the page.

```
<script src="menu_res.js"></script>
```

jQuery script in header

```
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Problem is it's not working on the subPages.

I have buttons in the other subPages too.

```
<a class="menu_button" id="res_menu" href="#"></a>
```

and

```
<a class="menu_button" id="res_menu_close" href="#"></a>
```

Im pretty new to the JS. Is there any way to tell if the script is even conncected ? Also it's a school project so nothing serious.

EDIT 1: There are no errors in the console.

Comment: If the problem is on the sub pages, I'm going to assume that means you are using some kind of directory/mod rewrite to create the sub page directories. If so, you simply need to update the `src` to go down to the root of the website by changing it to: `<script src="/menu_res.js"></script>`

Comment: Create a pen and update your question: https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: @imvain2 The script is right next to the index and other sub pages. But i will try.

Answer (score 0):

*be warned, I do not know what you mean, but i think you mean get the CSS sheet without coding it into HTML*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

This will import the CSS so all your ATR are in order for you to use.